# ajax get text of the option value in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a code that list all the values, I want written:

```
 <option th:each = "iName : ${iNames}" th:value = "${iName}" th:text = "${iName}" th:selected="${selectedIName == iName}"
```

and I have setSelectedName in my .js file

```
function setSelectedName() {
$('#NameForTypeSearch').ready(function() {
    $("#NameForSearch").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:  {keyname:$('#NameForSearch option:selected').text()}
        });
    });
});
```

I have text box named `NameForTypeSearch` and everytime the user selects an option, I want to use ajax to automatically input, the selected text in `NameForTypeSearch`. I can't get to work on my html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the jquery `val` function to get the `value` of the `option` element, as well as to set the `value` of the `input` element.

```js
$('#sel').change(function(){
    $('#output').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="output"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value you must use

```
$('#NameForSearch option:selected').val();
```

If you want get the option text you must use:

```
 $('#NameForSearch option:selected').html();
```

if you want put this value in other input you mustn´t use Ajax, just

```
$('#output').val("valueToSet");
```

Comment: so if I have `function setSelectedName() {
 $('#NameForSearch option: selected').val("NameForTypeSearch"); 
}` in my javascript and do onclick="javascript:setSelectedName" it should be working..

Comment: but when i do so, nothing happens if i click the option list.

Comment: Try with this listener:  $(document).on("change","#NameForSearch", function () {
   .......
});